# android-asyncTask keeps looping

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Im kinda new in android development, Im trying to do a login process for app, i have successfully complete the process with http post method on a php script on my local host, however to make my login process nicer i decided use progressdialog to show when the authentication process runs but the progress keeps looping. Below is my code:

LoginActivity.java - login button:

```
opt = new HttpRequest();
    btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                                                          

            v.setEnabled(false);
            AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                private boolean authResult = false;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
                    pd.setTitle("Processing...");
                    pd.setMessage("Please wait.");
                    pd.setCancelable(false);
                    pd.setIndeterminate(true);
                    pd.show();                                              
                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                    try {
                        //Do something...
                        if(opt.loginAuth(txtUsername.getText().toString(), txtPassword.getText().toString())){                  
                            Log.i(Data.tagInfo,"Redirecting to mainpage");
                            opt.showToast(LoginActivity.this,"Login Successful");
                            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.MainActivity"));

                        }
                        else{                   
                            opt.showToast(LoginActivity.this,"Login Fail");
                            Log.i(Data.tagError,"Login Fail");

                        }                                                           

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                    if (pd!=null) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        btnLogin.setEnabled(true);                          
                    }

                }

            };
            task.execute((Void[])null);     

        }
    });
```

HttpRequest.java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;


public class HttpRequest extends Operations {


public boolean loginAuth(String user , String pass){
    //Log.i("Info",user+"|"+pass);                             
     String     folder      =   "mobileapp",
                script      =   "/loginAuth_m-script.php",
                fullpath    =   folder+script,
                parameter   =   "username="+user+"&password="+pass,
                result      =   "";

    try {
        JSONArray jArray = convertJSON(new SendRequest().execute(fullpath,parameter).get());
        result = getSpecificJSONdata(jArray,"result");
        Log.i(Data.tagInfo,"Login result:"+result);
            if(result.equals(Data.success)){
                Log.i(Data.tagInfo,"loginAuth() return true");
                return true;
            }
            else{
                Log.i(Data.tagInfo,"loginAuth() return false");
                return false;
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.i(Data.tagError,"Error:"+e.toString());
        return false;
    }                                                                   
}

private class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HttpURLConnection connection;
            OutputStreamWriter request = null;
            URL url = null;   
            String response = null;         


                try
                {
                    url = new URL("http://"+Data.host+"/"+arg[0]);
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

                        request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                        request.write(arg[1]);
                        request.flush();
                        request.close();            


                            String line = "";               
                            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                            {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                            // Response from server after login process will be stored in response variable.                
                            response = sb.toString();
                            // You can perform UI operations here

                    Log.i("Info","Server Response:"+response);
                    isr.close();
                    reader.close();
                    return response;
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    Log.i("InfoError",e.toString());
                    return ""; 
                    // Error
                }


    }           
}



}
```

Thanks alot in advance^^

Comment: And you are postitive that you have a valid internet connection? Recently saw a q about HTTP not throwing Timout inside AsyncTask.

Comment: btw task.execute((Void[])null); can simply be task.execute(); or you can call execute directly // AsyncBody.. }.execute();

Comment: yes. i have successfully login before applying the progressdialog, after applying the progressdialog, it just keeps looping..

Comment: Well then either pd is null for some reason or onPostExecute is never called. Have you tried troubleshooting by writing logcat output in each situation to check this?

Comment: yes. i take notice on log cat, but no error is shown in logcat. I did some research, the problem is that on my asyncTask of the progressDialog, i am calling another asyncTask on my doInbackground, which is the asyncTask task to send httpRequest, which cause it to loop. So how can i call a asyncTask to show the progressDialog at the same time calls a asyncTask to send my request to the database?

Comment: I meant Log.d whether to debug where it is stuck. Nevertheless, you should never call another asynctask within doInBackground. Rather finish the first task and then fire the next in onPostExecute

Comment: Either that or do all the processing in the same asynctask of course.

Comment: In your case you can simply refactor the doInBackground part of SendRequest to a seperate method and call that directly (when you know that you are already in a background thread). Though, seperating the asynctasks has the nice sideeffect that you are able to update your progress text accordingly to what is happening.